# Nested dynamic form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling to get my head around some jQuery dynamically creating a form based on a selected input

I have tried generating new rows/inputs which works fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var conceptName = $('.addmore').find(":selected").text();
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="action.php">

  <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
    <select name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <select name="addmore[]" class="addmore form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get it so the user can keep adding rows, however, when the user then selects a number in one of the rows via select, it then generates x further fields but within that row only, so it's a dynamic field within another dynamic field.

So for example, below, 4 rows have been generated using the add another row button but on main row2, the user has selected the number 4 from the dropdown box which has generated 4 further rows (name) under main row2 heading.

```
[ main row ]
[ main row ]
[ main row2 ]
    [name] [name] [name] [name]
[ main row ]


[add another main row]
```

Comment: its not clear what the issue really is, can be explain please?

Comment: I'm struggling to create a bit of code that will generate another dynamic input * the number from the selected input. I'm trying to nest a dynamic fields, within dynamic fields. I have the first upper level done, I need to somehow nest within those fields now depending on the number selected (i.e selecting 5 will generate 5 text fields under the row already generated)

Comment: you mean if i select 4 and click add, the new select box also needs to have value 4?

Comment: No, not that. You can just keep clicking add and have 10 select boxes dynamically generated. However, I want it now, so when you select a number from any of those dropdowns you've just generated, it generates x amount of text fields within that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4dn702eo/ -- for anyone else looking at this/getting stuck after removing all and having to refresh the page ;)

Comment: I just want it so a user can select a number and it generates x number of text boxes. But then a new row can be added so then the user can now select x number of text boxes for that row, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add input boxes dynamically using `append('<input>')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var conceptName = $('.addmore').first().find(":selected").text();
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    html.replace('hide', '');
    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});

function selection(e) {
  $(e).parent().find('input').remove();
  for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(e.value); i++) {
    $(e).parent().append('<input>');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="action.php">

  <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
    <select name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <select name="addmore[]" class="addmore form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here" onchange="selection(this)">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate the response. The issue now though is that everytime it changes, it adds more fields so if I changed from 3 - 4, it adds them together. Also it only works on the last row that was inserted, no new ones?

Comment: You have no idea how long this has been racking my brain. Thank you!! Perfect